# Checking the "I have read..." box

Tags: halacha, emes-truth-honesty

A lot of computer programs, or online stores, have you check a box before completing installation or completing a transaction that says something along the lines of "I have read and agree to all of the jibber jabber in the above box."  I, for one, have never read any of that jibber jabber.  I am, however, happy to agree to whatever it says, knowing that they usually aren't that devious.

Is one allowed to check the "I have read..." box without having read it?

Comment: they are just asking you to agree.

Comment: @ray so if it just said "I agree" that would be fine; you can agree without reading.  But the question is whether you can check it if it specifically says "I have read" and you haven't read.

Comment: It is known that people do not read it,they just do it to cover themselves for lawsuits or in order to protect their license.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13577

Comment: Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37913

Answer (score 4):

It has been [demonstrated by experiment](http://www.foxnews.com/tech/2010/04/15/online-shoppers-unknowingly-sold-souls/), though not entirely scientifically, that the vast majority of people do not read EULAs. Thus, I would say there is an אנן סהדי that "I have read and agree" just means "I agree" in this case.