# Would halacha trust a password?

Tags: halacha, trust-neemanut

Almost all security systems in the modern world rely on a shared secret (password) system of some kind.  The premise is that no-one other than the account holder knows the secret, so anyone who knows the secret must be the account holder!

Is there a basis in Halacha for using a piece of secret information to establish credibility (נאמנות)?  I am looking for answers based on the rules of נאמנות only which do not rely on extra agreements between the parties.

Here are a few example cases where this would make a difference:

1. A Jewish bank offering online money transfer to Jewish customers.  What if the customer claims he never signed on and requested the money transfer?
2. Sending online payments to a Jewish vendor.  What if the vendor claims you sent it to the wrong place?
3. Trusting a Psak from an authority which is already נאמן.  For example, if I receive an e-mail from a someone claiming to be R' Chaim Kanievsky שליט''א (or his agent) and I want to verify it.  (You can use secure hashes to verify identity, they work like passwords).
4. ... lots more

Comment: Can you give an example where this would be useful?

Comment: @DoubleAA The same kinds of cases its used for in the modern world.  For example, if I have a bank account at a Jewish bank and they need to verify that I sent an instruction for them to make a payment, can they rely on a password?

Comment: Why would you think they can't? The customer agreed to those terms of service presumably

Comment: @DoubleAA How about _shelichus_ for a _get_, or similar?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm asking if based on pure halacha without outside agreements (like terms of service) you could rely on a password.  Could it create נאמנות the same way עדות or חזקה creates נאמנות.

Comment: Ploni, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! As @DoubleAA indicates, it will be a much stronger question if you [edit] in some suggestions for realms of Halacha or particular cases in which password-based trust may matter. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37913 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36924

Comment: I think that your first two examples have more basic issues: Who says that Halacha grants any status, outside whatever rules everyone involved consents to, to online funds transfers or payments?

Comment: @IsaacMoses It certainly does.  If I send a שליח with עדים that I told him to take a פקדון, the מופקד (the bank) would return it.  Later on if I complained, the bank would only need to bring the עדים to בית דין and I would lose.

Comment: Ploni, could you please explain what you mean? I don't see how describing a case with messengers and witnesses demonstrates that Halacha says anything about electronic funds transfers.

Comment: @IsaacMoses When I make a deposit at a bank, the bank becomes a *shomer* of that money.  They cannot transfer the money to a third party (electronic or otherwise) without my consent.  I am allowed to provide that consent via a *shliach* (messenger) as long as there are *eidim* (witnesses) that I actually appointed the *shliach*.  He is *neeman* (trusted) based on the testimony of the *eidim*.

Comment: @Ypnypn Can you detail how it would be used in that case? Who would provide the password to whom, and to what end? I don't understand how a password would be used in a Gittin case

Comment: Related: _Shof'tim_ 12:6

Comment: @msh210 Wow that is interesting.  Do you know of any mefarshim on that pasuk dealing w/ the questions in dinim?

Comment: @PloniAlmoni No. But I've not looked.

Comment: Yaakov Avinu relied on Simanim when he got married.